# Creating Table in UWP

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I am trying to make table in UWP, I already try to use GridView but I don't know how to add row from C# code. I need to add more rows because I will input more data every seconds.

Thanks

Comment: You can also refer UWP official documentation.
Visit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/layout-panels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's **no built-in data table** in UWP.

You add items (not rows) to a `GridView`. These items wrap to a new line automatically if they don't fit on the same line.

If you're looking for data entry (like your question suggests), take a look at the [Telerik Grid Component](http://www.telerik.com/universal-windows-platform-ui/grid) (which is free of use since they open sourced it in February 2017).

[image: Telerik Grid Component]